# What is the purpose of surrounding a variable/parameter with * (Star) symbols in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I saw this line of code in [Stripe.NETs documentation](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#creating-a-card)

```
TokenId = *tokenId*,
```

and...

```
StripeCard stripeCard = cardService.Create(*customerId*, myCard);
```

But I've never seen a variable/parameter surrounded by * (star) symbols before. Does this do anything special? Is this a .NET thing? C# thing?

Thankee mucho!

*`I remember * and ** are used as args and kwargs in python, and as a pointer to a var (*) or pointer to a pointer to a var (**) in C.`*

Comment: Did you tried it yourself to see what will happen?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I would imagine seeing a compile error wouldn't be too useful if one were to think it's used in a certain situation in C#. At least, it would potentially work in unsafe code (the first asterisk), but that's not what it represents in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means nothing in C#, so I'm assuming Stripe are using it to indicate that you should put your `tokenId` and `customerId` in their place.

Comment: No, it definitely means something, it means it won't compile. Asterisks can not be used outside of unsafe, and even then you can't have it after a variable.

Comment: @Dispersia exactly, they mean nothing. It is an indicate to replace `*tokenId*` and `*customerId*` with your specific values.

Comment: Thanks Steve, wasn't in a position yesterday to actually test the code and just was curious if it was something I hadn't seen before. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

They want to grab your attention by placing something between *.

e.g

```
var requestOptions = new StripeRequestOptions();
requestOptions.ApiKey = *optional*;              // this is not required unless you choose to pass the apikey on every service call
requestOptions.IdempotencyKey = "some string";   // this is for Idempotent Requests - https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=curl#idempotent_requests
requestOptions.StripeConnectAccountId = "acct_*" // if you are using Stripe Connect and want to issue a request on the connected account
```

All they want that you can replace a valid value with '**option**'